# Proof that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{x_n} = \sqrt{\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, inequality

It is asked to prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{x_n} = \sqrt{\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_n}$, and suggested to use the following two inequalities:

$$a+b\leq a+ 2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}+b$$
$$\sqrt{b}\sqrt{b}\leq \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$$

The second inequality holds iff $a\geq b \geq 0$.

I've tried different possibilities, but couldn't figure out how to either take the limit sign out of the square root, or take the limit sign into the square root. Would appreciate some hints, but not an entire solution please.

Comment: Don't fiddle around with limit signs. If $x_n \to L$, you need to show that $\sqrt{x_n} \to \sqrt{L}$. Given a bound for $|x_n - L|$, can you get a bound for $|\sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{L}|$?

Comment: I'm not sure where to use the above inequalities. Please let me know what you think about my proof:

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n = T \implies \sqrt{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n} =\sqrt{T}$. Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n = T$, $\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists N>0$ such that $\left| x_n-T \right|<\varepsilon$ for $n>N$. Thus $T-\varepsilon <x_n<T+\varepsilon \implies \sqrt{x_n}<\sqrt{T+\varepsilon}$.
Now, $\sqrt{x_n}<\sqrt{T+\varepsilon}\leq \sqrt{T}+\sqrt{\varepsilon}:=\varepsilon_1\iff \left|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{T}\right|<\varepsilon_1 \implies \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{x_n}=\sqrt{T}$.

Comment: I think you missed one step. Why $\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{T} < \sqrt{\varepsilon}$ implies $|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{T}| < \sqrt{\varepsilon}$?

Comment: for the second comment, you can choose $|T-x_n|\lt \epsilon^2$ and show with the same proof you wrote that $|sqrt(T)-sqrt(x_n)|\lt \epsilon . for the third, by the [triangle inequality](https://youtu.be/051WWg9twO0?si=NNCX9umOGFnZ1mNA/)  and by $\sqrt{a}>0  \sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{T}=|\sqrt{x_n}+(-|\sqrt{T}|)\ge |\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{T}|$ and thus $ |\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{T}|\le |\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{T}|<\sqrt{\epsilon}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $x_n\geq 0$. Otherwise the limit doesn't exist because the sequence $\{\sqrt{x_n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ isn't even defined(well, in $\mathbb{R}$).

Suppose the statement above is true. Let $A=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x_n$ Then there are 2 cases:

(1)$A=0$. $\forall\epsilon>0$,$\exists N\in\mathbb{N}^*$ so that $\forall n\geq N$ there is $x_n<\epsilon^2$,that is, $\sqrt{x_n}<\epsilon$, so that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x_n}=0=\sqrt{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n}$.

(2)Otherwise,$A>0$. $\forall\epsilon>0$,$\exists N\in\mathbb{N}^*$ so that $\forall n\geq N$ there is $|x_n-A|<\sqrt{A}\epsilon$.This means that $\epsilon>\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{A}}\geq|\frac{x_n-A}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{A}}|=|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{A}|$, therefore $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{x_n}=\sqrt{A}=\sqrt{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n}$.

This proof uses solely the definition of the limit of a sequence :)

Comment: I don't understand where "...there is $x_n < \sqrt{A}\epsilon$..." comes from? $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = A$. Hence this should be $|x_n - A|<\sqrt{A}\epsilon$.

Comment: @alexander.myltsev Sorry for the mistake. I have fixed it now.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It isn't clear now why "...This means that $\varepsilon > \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{A}}$..." is true?

Comment: I think the step is pretty clear: $\varepsilon > \frac{|x_n - A|}{\sqrt{A}} = \frac{|x_n - A|}{|\sqrt{A}|} = |\frac{x_n - A}{\sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{A}}|=|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{A}| $. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The second equality should be $\geq$ instead

Answer (score -1):

It's wrong of course.

For $x_n\geq0$ it's true because $f$ is a continuous function, where $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: What do you mean "it's wrong of course"?

Comment: @ Najib Idrissi I meant that for $x_n<0$ your statement is wrong, which says that your statement is wrong.

Comment: There has to be some confusion here. There is no "my statement", the only thing I did in this thread is ask you a question. And OP's question completely obviously assumes that $x_n \ge 0$, if only because they're taking the square root of $x_n$ without saying anything...

Comment: I don't agree with you. You must say that $x_n\geq0$, otherwise your statement is wrong.

Comment: What on Earth are you calling "my statement"?! OP's statement? And there's a difference between "wrong" and "a hypothesis wasn't written down but is implicitly assumed otherwise what's written down makes no sense".

Comment: I don't like a math in which a wrong statement, changes by something, which  "implicitly assumed". I think it's not math.

Comment: A ton of things are implicitly assumed in math writing.